# installing laravel --prefer-dist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am following the Laravel installation on their website
and I came across this line

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Now, what exactly does the `--prefer-dist` part mean? I can't see anything on their documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's all available here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

> **--prefer-dist:** Reverse of --prefer-source, composer will install from dist if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build
>   servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of
>   the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with git if you
>   do not have a proper setup.

Comment: Hi @Marwelln . May I ask what's the difference if I put `--prefer-dist` and not? Is there any effects in the installation? Or Still the same? and just speed up the installation?

Comment: What does "dist" mean ?

Comment: @Sliq it measn "distributable"

Comment: @Marwellen: I wish anyone would you would have answered Jonjie's question.

Answer (score 113):

`--prefer-dist` and `--prefer-source` are the two options of **composer** which included in various documentations with a lack of proper explanation.

`--prefer-dist` would try to download and unzip archives of the dependencies using GitHub or another API when available. This is used for faster downloading of dependencies in most cases. It doesn't download the whole VCS history of the dependencies and it should be better cached. Also archives on GitHub could exclude some files you don't need for just using the dependency with .gitattributes exclude directive.

`--prefer-source` would try to clone and keep the whole VCS repository of the dependencies when available. This is useful when you want to have the original VCS repositories cloned in your vendor/ folder. E.g. you might want to work on the dependencies - modify them, fork them, submit pull requests etc. while also using them as part of the bigger project which requires them in the first place.

Simply speaking, the `--prefer-source` option will prefer to create a package directory that is a "version control repository", which is equivalent to you typing:

`$ git clone ...`

or

`$ svn checkout ...`

On the other hand, the `--prefer-dist` option will prefer to create a non-"version control repository", which is equivalent to you typing:

`$ git clone ... ; rm -fr dir/.git`

or

`$ svn export ...`

Remember that, these are only preferences, if a dependency is required using a VCS repository which does not provide archives such as GitHub API, then the only available option is to clone the repository.

Comment: I like you... They always try to hide something just like we are in babyhood, or just copy and paste from the document they even don't know.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference if I put `--prefer-dist` and not? Is there any effects in the installation? Or Still the same? and just speed up the installation?

Comment: @Jonjie --prefer-dist is default.

Answer (score 1):

As per the link :
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Here is the documentation statement for the question :-

--prefer-install: There are two ways of downloading a package: source and dist. Composer uses dist by default. If you pass --prefer-install=source (or --prefer-source) Composer will install from source if there is one. This is useful if you want to make a bugfix to a project and get a local git clone of the dependency directly. To get the legacy behavior where Composer use source automatically for dev versions of packages, use --prefer-install=auto. See also config.preferred-install. Passing this flag will override the config value.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.