# What does --prefer-dist mean when using create-project to install laravel4?

Tags: laravel-4

What does `--prefer-dist` mean when using create-project to install laravel4?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079571/installing-laravel-prefer-dist and it is also documented in the composer documentation and discussed in other resources. There is no way you could have missed it if you had made an attempt to Google it yourself first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing laravel --prefer-dist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079571/installing-laravel-prefer-dist)

Answer (score 0):

`--prefer-dist`: Reverse of `--prefer-source`; composer will install from dist if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with Git if you do not have a proper setup.